# Access Query Total Sum between Dates

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm looking a way to calculate the total quantity purchased between a specific dates and returns just one entry based on the item name. Here's the sample of my table and the result that I need:
[Sample Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QzPws.png)

I'm not sure if Access have the capability to do this, I tried to use different formula and even grouping it together, but it didn't come out as what I need. 
I did quite a bit of research as well, but none of them have the result I want. I really need to know the answer, it driving me nuts. Anyway, thank you beforehand for anyone that can help me.

Comment: Can you post the sql you have used so far? I'd be happy to show you, but not without seeing where your effort has led you.

Comment: And yes, Access has the capability to do this.

Comment: @ChristopherD. Well, I tried the `between #Date1# and #Date2#` - didn't work, still showing multiples entry of the same item; tried the dsum formula, but all of them showing the the record with the total sum instead.

Comment: Ok, if you could paste the sql, then I don't have to use placeholders for your field and table names..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Use query designer
- select your table
- select the three fields you want (ItemName, Quantity, PurchaseDate)
- create selection criteria
- select 'Totals' option in Ribbon
- Make 'Date'= 'WHERE'
- Make 'Quantity' = 'SUM'
- Let 'ItemName' default to 'GROUP BY'
- Run the query

Here's a sample:

```
SELECT Sum(Table1.Quantity'SUM) AS SumOfQuantity'SUM, Table1.ItemName
FROM Table1
WHERE (((Table1.PurchaseDate) Between #1/1/2000# And #12/31/2015#))
GROUP BY Table1.ItemName;
```

Comment: I tried the same thing as what you posted, but still leave the 'Date' to 'Group By'. I guess that is why it didn't work before. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Yes, you can't use 'Date' as a GROUP BY or it will return one row for each unique date (In addition to grouping by  ItemName)  :)